# How to test outoing traffic on random ports? (on OS X)

Tags: firewall, ip, network-access, testing, port-security

In some situations or on some locations, I'm struggling with restricted **outgoing** traffic. For example a restricted LAN where outgoing traffic is only allowed on limited ports.

I know how to check or test my connection or network for *incoming* traffic on various ports. But I can't find how to do the opposite: checking on what ports I can make *outgoing* connections from my device.

Does anyone know how to do this? E.g. a way to probe a range of ports (regardless to what external server or IP).

I assume there a different ways to do this for different platforms: in this case I'm on OS X.

Note that I'm not dealing with a firewall or restriction on my own device, it's not a matter of local system configuration. I'm connected through a LAN which appears to have a very restrictive firewall or router or something, and I need to find out to which ports I can still connect to the outside world.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, I see. Would it be OK if I change my inquiry to "how to" rather than asking for a specific tool or script? If there is some fancy shell command or other technical solution to this, that would suit my need just as well.

Comment: You can certainly edit your question to ask how, but I don't think you would like an answer which says you need a firewall which filters in both directions. That seems to leave you in the same place you are now, asking which one to use.

Comment: I actually don't need a firewall, it appears (in some cases) there is a firewall in place on the LAN I'm connected to, and I'm just trying to find out which ports are still open / accessible (for outgoing traffic). So I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you need help with your OS, you could ask on the SE site for the OS, e.g. [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) for OSX, or on [su]. Host configurations are also off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks but the restriction is not related to my OS. It's something in my LAN (a large corporate network) and I don't know what or where or how. I assume they have some firewall or router or NAT thing in place which restricts outgoing traffic.

Comment: Unless the network is under your direct control, the question is explicitly off-topic here. You really should read the [help] for an SE site on which you wish to ask a question. There is a _[What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)_ section.

Comment: @RonMaupin OK, considering I'm interested in just any solution (not a specific tool or product per se), what would be a better SE site for this topic?

Comment: As I suggested earlier, you could try to ask this on [su]. You should read the help center there to see if the question is on-topic for that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a program like NMAP to determine what ports are open to what addresses. Security operations(assuming your network has a security team) may not appreciate this as it will look suspicious when you are scanning networks for open ports.

https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html